# If $\text{Var}(X) < \infty$, is $\text{Var}(XY) < \infty$ for $0 \le Y \le 1$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, bounds

I have a variable $X$ that I know has finite variance (and therefore also finite mean). Is it always true that its variance remains finite after scaling by $0 \le Y \le 1$?

Note that $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily independent.

Edit: I believe the "worst-case" $Y$ is $0$ whenever $X < c$ and $1$ whenever $X \ge c$, for some $c$ (and the mirrored case)?

Comment: Is $Y$ a random variable?

Comment: Yes but it may depend on $X$.

Comment: An utterly trivial inequality sometimes is quite useful in such situations: $\mathbb{E}(X^2Y^2) \le \mathbb{E}(X^2)\sup(Y^2)$. (This is perhaps the simplest special case of [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality) for $p=1,q=\infty$ applied to $X^2$ and $Y^2$.)

Comment: Thanks whuber. I believe this leads to the correct solution (see the answer I made)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've unaccepted kjetil's answer since, as was pointed out in the comments, it assumes $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

The following answer should work when $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, by using whuber's suggestion:

\begin{align}
\text{Var}(XY) &= E((XY)^2) - E(XY)^2 \\
&\le E(X^2Y^2) \\
&\le E(X^2)\sup(Y^2) \\
&= E(X^2) \\
&= \text{Var}(X) + E(X)^2 \\
&< \infty 
\end{align}

Note that the result also holds for any bounded $Y$ (since $\sup(Y^2)$ will be finite).

Comment: Also note that we can conclude $|E(XY)| \le \sqrt{\text{Var}(X) + E(X)^2}$, since $\text{Var}(XY) \ge 0 \implies E(XY)^2 \le E((XY)^2)$.

Comment: I don't believe kjetil assumed independence between $X$ and $Y$. The law of total variation holds in general, and not assuming independence. So I can find nothing in his statement that assumes independence. Also notice that your conclusion is exactly the same as my conclusion that is based off of kjetil's answer.

Comment: Independence must have been used somewhere (I guess when factoring out the expectation), otherwise the first equation from your answer (as shown in my comment) is stating that $\text{Var}(XY)$ is the same whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are independent, which is a contradiction. The fact that we came to the same conclusion is kind of a "coincidence", because we are both giving upper bounds. Mine comes from dropping the $E(XY)^2$ term and $Y^2 \le \sup(Y^2)$, and yours comes from $\text{Var}(Y), E(Y^2) \le \sup(Y^2)$.

Comment: I think I figured out where kjetil is using independence. By the law of total variance $Var(XY) = Var(E(XY|Y)) + E(Var(XY|Y))$. If we just look at the first term $Var(E(XY \mid Y)) = Var(Y^2E(X \mid Y))$ which is not the same as $Var(Y^2E(X))$. It is the same only when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: Yes that sounds right to me (I'd upvote but don't have the privilege). I think the same thing happens with the other term as well. Specifically, $E(Var(XY | Y)) = E(Y^2 Var(X|Y))$ which is not the same as $E(Y^2 Var(X))$. Thanks for helping clear that up. :)

Comment: Yep, that happens with the other term as well. I am glad this has cleared.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the formula 
$$  \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{\mathbb{V}} \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
   \Var (XY) = \E (\Var (XY | Y)) + \Var (\E (XY | Y))
$$
where $\Var $ is the variance operator. Take it term for term, write $\mu=\E X, \sigma^2=\Var X$, $\E (XY | Y= y) = \E (yX) = y \E (X) =\mu y$ with variance (over $Y$) $\Var (\mu Y) $ which is finite since $Y$ is bounded.

Then the other term, $\Var (XY | Y=y) = \Var (yX) = y^2 \Var (X) = \sigma^2 y^2$ which again has a finite expectation since $Y$ is bounded. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Nice. To check my understanding this is using the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)? Also this seems to prove something more general: that the variance $XY$ is finite as long as the variance of both $X$ and $Y$ are finite?

Comment: Yes, it is total variance. And no, your last claim is untrue. I used  that $Y$ is bounded, which implies its variance exists.  I guess it would be easy to make an example where variance of $X$ and $Y$ both exist, but their product has infinite variance.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry but I'm confused. According to the formula in Greenparker's answer based on the above, this will still hold as long as $E(Y^2)$ and $Var(Y)$ are finite? And if $Var(Y)$ is finite, then so is $E(Y)^2$, and therefore $E(Y^2)$ as well. So how does my claim break down? Also thank you!

Comment: @Aaron Voelker: you are right.

Comment: Actually I'm confused again... I think the above answer only works when $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*... Please see my response to Greenparker below.

Comment: @Aaron Voelker:  There is no need for independence in the calculations.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen $\mathbb{E}(XY \mid Y=y) = \mathbb{E}(yX)$ does not hold without some assumptions (such as independence).

Comment: For a counterexample, let $X$ and $Y$ be Bernoulli with $P(X=Y=1)=0.5$. Then $\mathbb{E}(XY \mid Y = 1) = 1 \neq 0.5 = \mathbb{E}(1\,X)$

Comment: @Juho $\mathbb{E}(1 X) = \mathbb{E}(X)=0.5$, too.  The relation $\mathbb{E}(XY\mid Y=y)=\mathbb{E}(X)y$ is an example of a very general theorem called "taking out what is known."  It does not require independence of $(X,Y)$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties.

Comment: @whuber: indeed $\mathbb{E}(1\,X) = \mathbb{E}(X) = 0.5$ as I, too, said in my comment.  What do you think $\mathbb{E}(XY \mid Y= 1)$ is in the case where $X=Y$ almost surely?  If you refer to the  "Pulling out known factor" property in the Wikipedia link, wouldn't that lead to $\mathbb{E}(XY  \mid Y = y) =  y\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y)$, where the latter factor of the right hand side does not necessarily equal $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Comment: @Juho Sorry, my comment was stupid.  Of course I needed to write the conditional expectation in $\mathbb{E}(XY\mid Y=y)=\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y=y) y$.  For some reason I just automatically understood these expectations as being conditional even when they weren't... .